# Cucumber no output screen

Tags: ruby, cucumber, automated-tests, watir

I'm pretty new to cucumber automated testing.  When I first started, a co-worker had set up everything for me on my computer, and (now that he's gone) I've run into a problem that I can't seem to figure out.

I'm using cucumber to test a web application.  In the past when I run the script, an internet explorer pops up, and I can see each line of the script being executed.

I recently had to reinstall cucumber, ruby, watir, etc., and **that internet explorer screen no longer pops up.**

I installed Ruby 1.9.3, cucumber (gem install cucumber), watir (gem install watir). Am I missing something?  Is it an extra plug in?  The script still runs.  However, instead of taking say 1 min + to run a 320 step script, it now takes 1.5 seconds.  There are no error messages. When run from the command window, it literally looked like it just scrolled through the script instead of going through each step.

What is the pop up screen called anyways?  A scenario screen?  Output screen?

It was really difficult for me to look it up on google because I had no idea how to refer to that screen.

Any help is appreciated. and I realize I might not have described the problem well enough.  Just leave a comment, and I can try to clarify it more.

---

```
Feature:
'To go to a webpage'

Scenario:
#   ----------
#   GO TO PAGE
#   ----------
    Given that I have gone to the Login page at "url"
#
#   ----------
#   LOG IN
#   ----------  
    When I add "username" to the Username
    When I add "password" to the Password
    And click the Login button
    Then "Welcome" should be mentioned on the page
```

script definitions:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir"


puts "Browser is running..."
END {
puts "Closing browser..."
}
BEGIN {
puts "Starting browser..."
}
Given /^that I have gone to the Login page at "(.*)"$/ do |item|
@browser = Watir::IE.start(item)
   lnk_found = 0
   @browser.links.each do |lnk|
     if lnk.id.to_s.matches("overridelink")
        lnk_found += 1
     end
   end
   if lnk_found > 0
      @browser.link(:id, "overridelink").click
   end
#   puts "Watir Version:  #{Watir::IE::VERSION}"
   @browser.maximize
end
#
#
#
When /^I add "(.*)" to the Username$/ do |item|
@browser.text_field(:name, "loginName").set(item)
end
#
#
When /^I add "(.*)" to the Password$/ do |item|
@browser.text_field(:name, "passwd").set(item)
end
#
#
#
Then /^"(.*)" should be mentioned on the page$/ do |item|
   if @browser.text.include?(item)
#      puts "TEST PASSED.  FOUND >#{item}<"
   else
      puts "*** TEST FAILED ***.  >#{item}< was not found."
   end
end
```

Directory Structure

```
Cucumber
    Testing
       lib
         login.rb
       login.feature
```

Comment: Please provide some example code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: i added some code but i can't add too much because it is work related and confidential. keep in mind, in the past i had no problem with this script, it was not ultered, i only reinstalled everything, then the browser stopped showing. to me it seems like more of a installation issue then the coding itself but i'm not sure

Comment: Are you sure you are running the tests the same way as you did before? It sounds like you might have two problems - (1) You are not actually running your tests (ie this is why the duration is too short) and (2) You are not calling your custom report formatter.

Comment: i'm positive i'm running the tests just like before because it's the only way i know how to run the tests. and it does seem like the tests aren't actually running cause it's way too short. feels like the script definitions might not be loading. however, i don't think there's an issue with the directory structure because it've always worked in the past. and from what i know, cucumber flattens the directory under the root and reads .rb as script def and .features as features.

Comment: Do you know what versions of the gems you were using before? Doing `gem install watir` installs the latest version of the gem. Given your code has `Watir::IE.start`, you were not likely using the latest code before - to my knowledge, `Watir::IE.start` has to be replaced by `Watir::Browser.start`. You might have similar issues in Cucumber gem changes.

Comment: after some research i suspect the problem is like u said changes in the versions of the gems. i have no idea what versions they were before because i didn't set them up but watir (4.0.2 x86-mingw32) and cucumber (1.3.3) are the versions now. i tried changing from IE to Browser but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: How are you running your tests (eg what command)? Your directory structure will typically throw a `You don't have a 'features' directory` warning, which results in no tests found/run.

Comment: in the past i've ran it with cucumber login.feature in the Testing folder....and it've always worked...until the re-installation. i was told on another forum to just do cucumber Testing from the root directory...but  that gives me another error message..

Starting browser...
cannot load such file -- watir/ie (LoadError)

Comment: Are you doing `require 'watir/ie'` somewhere? If so, then your original watir version is probably really old - perhaps 1.6.5. Depending how much code you have, you might want to try uninstalling the watir gem and trying older versions OR upgrade your code.

Comment: i think i'm going to try updating the code. so to clarify newer watir versions does not require me to put "require 'watir/ie'" somewhere right?

Comment: Correct. The only thing you need for watir is `require 'watir'`.

Comment: so i updated my code, took out some lines that i think weren't necessary anymore. left require 'watir' there like you said. and it magically worked. thanks alot for your help. if you would like stick an answer below and i'll mark it correct and u can get the points or w.e for it =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly fixed it but after taking suggestions and advices from different people I basically uninstalled and reinstalled watir several times.

I also updated the code, took out "require 'rubygems'" and replaced Watir::IE.start with Watir::Browser.start.

It seems like the problem was the existing scripts I worked with was based off of older versions of watir/cucumber/ruby, so when I had to reinstall everything, the scripts were no longer compatible with newer versions of everything.